# Show that for $u, v \in \mathbb{Z} $ there are only a finite number of $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $(ab)^2-ua-vb$ is a square.

Tags: diophantine-equations, square-numbers

This is a generalization
of my question
[Which positive integers $a$ and $b$ make $(ab)^2-4(a+b) $ a square of an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897406/which-positive-integers-a-and-b-make-ab2-4ab-a-square-of-an-integer)

Show that
for
$u, v \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$
there are only
a finite number of
$a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$
such that
$(ab)^2-ua-vb$
is a square.

(I.e., all variables are positive.)

Note that
there are two cases
(at least in my analysis):

(1) $a$ and $b$
are sufficiently large.
In this case,
there are upper bounds
on $a$ and $b$.

(2) $a$ or $b$ is small enough
so that the bounds
in case (1)
do not apply.
In this case
it has to be shown that
for any $a$
there are only
a finite number of $b$
so that
the expression is a square
(and similarly for $b$).

Comment: You need some restrictions on $u$ and $v$, as it fails if $u=v=0$.

Comment: It also fails by taking $(a,b)=(cv,-cu)$, so you need some restrictions on $a$ and $b$ as well.

Comment: All of a, b, u, v are positive.

Comment: Is it a problem from any book or a new problem by yourself so that there is no evidence yet that the statement is true? I'm asking just because proving an already-true statement and a statement which is not may require different thinking :)

Comment: For $u=v$, this can be approached in the same way as the answer in the linked question. Similarly, we get $$\left( a - \frac u2 \right) \left( b - \frac u2 \right) \le \frac{u^2}{4} - \frac 12$$